# Can you use Nulls as part of a multi-column uniqueness check in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, null, constraints, unique-constraint

Consider a simple self-referencing table in SQLite with the following fields

```
Create Table Test{
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, <-- Alias for the RowId
    Name TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(length(Name) > 0),
    ParentId INTEGER REFERENCES Test(Id),
};

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_UniqueNamePerLevel ON Test(ParentId, Name);
```

We're trying to set a uniqueness constraint on Name for all items which share the same ParentId.  In other words, you can have two items with the name 'Joe' provided those items do not have the same ParentId.

The problem is that SQLite seems to treat nulls as distinct, meaning for any level except root items, the constraint works, but you can have fifteen 'Joe' entries all with a ParentId of 'null.'

Bonus points if you can show how to make that constraint trim leading and trailing whitespace on insert/update, and ignore case for the uniqueness constraint too.

Comment: What specific problem do you have with writing the trigger?

Comment: I'm speaking of a constraint, not a trigger.  The trigger was mentioned as a bonus question if you will.  I mean I guess we could try using the trigger for a constraint, but I'm not sure that's a good design. Then again if it works and its easily read, perhaps it is.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite treats NULLs in UNIQUE constraints as distinct [for compatibility with other databases](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html).

It is not possible to use a CHECK constraint for this because it would have to access other rows from the table, but subqueries are not allowed in CHECK.

You would have to use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Test_ParentName_unique_insert_check
AFTER INSERT ON Test
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.ParentId IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'root items must be unique, too')
    FROM Test
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL
      AND Name = NEW.Name
      AND Id <> NEW.Id;
END;
```

Comment: I was about to say this only checks root names, but then I realized you meant to use this *with* the unique index, not instead of it.  But that said, if the only reason for the index was to enforce uniqueness and nothing else (we're never using that for a select, etc.) would it make sense to remove the index (which would speed up inserts) and *just* use this trigger (with the logic updated for all levels, not just the root of course, then removing the 'when' clause)?

Comment: Yes, but you'd still need some index for the lookup to be efficient.

Comment: One other thing... why use an AFTER then check ID <> NEW.ID vs just doing a before?

Comment: Because NEW.ID [might not be available](https://www.sqlite.org/mark/lang_createtrigger.html?Cautions&The+val*ger.#mark) in a BEFORE trigger.

Comment: That may be true, but in a BEFORE trigger, why do you need NEW.ID in the first place?  In that case the record hasn't been inserted yet so you don't need to filter it out, therefore you don't need the ID. You only need to check the Name and Parent ID which will be there. (I also saw you had, then removed your other comment.)